# экспорт данных из test.rar\test.csv в ms sql таблицу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать экспорт данных из test.rar\test.csv в ms sql таблицу  с кирилицей  с помощью скрипта
[image: пример таблицы]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: INSERT INTO table FROM OPENROWSET/OPENQUERY

Comment: rar предварительно распаковать. csv импортировать с помощью [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: нужно именно что бы через sql открывать rar ,bulk insert делал с цсв там остается проблема с тем что кирилица не корректно вставляется в таблицу

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец данных, т.е. CREATE table плюс *.csv.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.